# Formatting my Output

Tags: java, formatting

I'm supposed to make a class and a runner that takes in 4 variables and uses them to calculate the slope of the line. My problem is I don't know how to format my output so that I don't have such a long decimal.The formatting output I am supposed to use is: out.println(String.format("%.3f",dec))                 Here is the code for my class.

```
public class Line
 {
  private int xOne;
  private int yOne;
  private int xTwo;
  private int yTwo;
  private double slope;

 public Line(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2)
 {
  int xOne = x1;
  int yOne = y1;
  int xTwo = x2;
  int yTwo = y2; 

 }

 public void setCoordinates(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2)
 {
  xOne = (int) x1;
  yOne = (int) y1;
  xTwo = (int) x2; 
  yTwo = (int) y2;

 }

public void calculateSlope( )
{
   slope = (yTwo - yOne) / (xTwo - xOne); 


}

public void print( )
{

    System.out.println( "The slope is " + slope); 

  }
 }
```

And here is the code for my runner.

```
  public class LineRunner
 {
 public static void main( String[] args )
  {
  Line test = new Line(1,9,14,2);
  test.calculateSlope();
  test.print();

  test.setCoordinates(1,7,18,3);
  test.calculateSlope();
  test.print();
  }
 }
```

Any help would be awesome!

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I need to use this code: out.println(String.format("%.3f",dec))    (or something like it) in my program to format my output.

Comment: Yes, but what is your **question**?

Comment: How would I use that code... I dont understand where I will put it inside of my program.

Comment: _format my output_ Where do you produce output?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis in my runner class in the test.print

Answer (score 0):

You can use [DecimalFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html):

```
DecimalFormat twoDForm = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
System.out.println(Double.valueOf(twoDForm.format(slope)));
```

You can even set how you want to do the rounding if needed, eg:

```
twoDForm.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.CEILING);
```

Comment: I'm sorry I'm really new to java, so where would i put this code? In my runner or in my class, and where in which of those?

Comment: You could do it in the print() method.

DecimalFormat twoDForm = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
System.out.println(Double.valueOf("The slope is " + twoDForm.format(slope)));

Comment: when i put that in my public void print () I got an error.The error says DecimalFormat cannot be resolved to a type

Comment: Sorry for the delay. You can add an import statement at the top of your program:
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

If you are using an IDE such as Netbeans or Eclipse, it would be easier to organize the imports.